# Giving values using a switch

Tags: netlogo

I want to set two values for a patch using a switch, I mean if the switch is "on" set 1 if it´s "off" set 0. First of all I created the switch, then I wrote the next code.

```
SET LL 1 if (lluvia = "on") and 0 if (lluvia = "off")
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Switch gives you a boolean value and you can use it directly in `ifelse`:

```
ifelse lluvia [set LL 1] [set LL 0]
```

BTW, in NetLogo it is common to name a boolean variable with a question mark. Name `lluvia?` would be more in NetLogo style.

Comment: It works. Thanks for taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution:

```
set LL ifelse-value lluvia [1] [0]
```

I think bergant's answer actually reads better, though.